# ML: Generate a score between 0-100 as as the result using the given features

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I am working on a project where I have the data of customers to whom we need to sell the product. I want to score the customers between 0 to 100 where 100 tells us that the customer buys from us and 0 customer does not buy from us. Please check out this link for my code and the dataset I used: https://github.com/karthikbhandary2/Score-Generation